# Sorting data with numbers first and alphabet next in java

Tags: java, sorting, alphanumeric, treeset, alphabet

Hi I have a list of input as a string and it will contain full digits{digits} or a combination of {character}{digits} I want in sorting in the below order using java.

input : { "1", "21","12","12345", "CA23456","CA123", "IND123"}
Output: {"1","12","21","12345","CA123","CA23456","IND123"}

Comment: `Collections#sort` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Please provide your snippet, then tell us what you can't do, and what you want to achieve. This plain text isn't much of a help for us to help you.

Comment: please provide the format of your array element i.e. how the element would be constructed... is it possible to have a element like this "CA123TU" where only middle portion is the number? I am seeing two types: {Digits}, {Characters}{Digits}. Is it possible that you can have {Digits}{Characters}{Digits}, or may be {Characters}{Digits}{Characters} etc. ? pls reply as soon as possible..

Comment: I will have only {digits} or {digital}{characters} in my list

Comment: @swethaharidoss, but i am seeing {Characters}{Digits} like: "CA123"? How do u explain that? pls make a clear statement...

Comment: someone closed the question. But did u get your answer?

Comment: I didnt get my answer... Sorry I will have {digits} or {character} {digits} in my list.

Comment: okay, answering is blocked is in this post,...see in your other post I've posted an answer...i mean [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63186512/sorting-numbers-1st-and-alphabets-next-in-java/63191334#63191334).

Answer (score 0):

If the string would be proper JSON it would be much easier. But here is a proposal:

```
void orderStringList(final String str) {
     List<String> parts = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9,]", "").split(",");
     Collections.sort(parts);
     return parts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convert the input to a list, then, sort it using a custom `Comparator` as follows:

```
String inp = "{ \"1\", \"21\",\"12\",\"12345\", \"CA23456\",\"CA123\", \"IND123\"}";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(inp.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9,]", "").split(",")));
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
     private boolean areNumbers(String a, String b) {
          return isNumber(a) && isNumber(b);
     }
     private boolean isNumber(String s) {
          return s.matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+");
     }
     @Override
     public int compare(String a, String b) {
          int comp = !areNumbers(a, b)
                     ? a.compareTo(b)
                     : Integer.parseInt(a) - Integer.parseInt(b);
          return comp;
     }
});
System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[1, 12, 21, 12345, CA123, CA23456, IND123]
```